# How to say year-on-year in Russian?

Tags: лексикон

Is there any fixed phrase for 'year-on-year' in Russian?

Answer (score 7):

In news this phrase is usually sounds as "По сравнению с аналогичным периодом предыдущего года":

> Мировые продажи корпорации Toyota Motor с января по сентябрь текущего года достигли 7,41 млн автомобилей. И хотя **по сравнению с аналогичным периодом предыдущего года** это изменение незначительно — всего 0,1%, этого оказалось достаточно, чтобы Toyota сохранила мировое лидерство и оставила позади General Motors и Volkswagen. - [kommersant.ru](http://www.kommersant.ru/doc/2330446)

If the periods are equal to year, then you can use  `по сравнению с предыдущим годом`, `в годовом исчислении` (about interest rates).

Other alternatives from [multitran.ru](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?CL=1&s=year-on-year&l1=1) include `годичный`, `в течение года` or even `год к году`.

So, to pick the right translation you should look at the context where year-on-year is used.